# Converting object series in Black Friday Dataset to int, using anaconda

Tags: python, types, int, converters

i am using the Black Friday Data set to Predict purchase amount.

This is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import sklearn 
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    from  mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report
    from sklearn import datasets
    train=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\data sets\\train.csv")
    test=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\data sets\\test.csv")
    import numpy as np
    frames=[train,test]
    data=pd.concat(frames)
```

And I amtrying to convert the Age and Current city tears object series to integers by coding:

```
    data["Age"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

or 
        pd.to_numeric(data["City_Category"])
        data["City_Category"].astype(int)

But it converts all my features to objects and I don't understand why and how to fix it ?

```
City_Category                 object
Gender                        object
Marital_Status                object
Occupation                    object
Product_Category_1            object
Product_Category_2            object
Product_Category_3            object
Product_ID                    object
Purchase                      object
Stay_In_Current_City_Years    object
User_ID                       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: `data["Age"] = data["Age"].astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good approach to go through the dataset first.

**AGE**: In the column `Age`, the values are like this: `'0-17'`. You need to modify it before doing any operation on it.

The easiest way is to take a middle single value which will be understandable to the machine. Almost like this:

```
data['Age'] = data['Age'].map({'0-17': 15,
                               '18-25': 20})
```

Later on, you can normalise this column.

**City Category**: The next column is `City_Category`. It has categorical data i.e `A, B, C`. To handle this data, you can use `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

The output value will be : `0, 1 ,2`.

Comment: can i use for these :"from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder" pd.get_dummies:

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and try it.